# How to create an array with one object using XSLT transformation

Tags: json, xml, xslt

XML:

```
<binning base-url="url">
<binning-set label="XYZ" bs-id="label_1">
  <bin label="yes" ndocs="9868" token="label_1==yes"/>
</binning-set>
<binning-set label="Gender" bs-id="label_2">
 <bin label="Male" ndocs="89076" token="label_2==Yes"/>
 <bin label="Female" ndocs="43567" token="label_2==No"/>
</binning-set>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="binning-set">
   <bin type="array">
    <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/> 
     <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
     </bin>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected response:

```
            {
        "label": "XYZ",
        "bs-id": "label_1",
        "bin":           **[**  {
           "label": "yes",
           "ndocs": "9868",
           "token": "label_1==yes"
        }
         **]**
     },
              {
        "label": "Gender",
        "bs-id": "gender_label",
        "bin":             [
                          {
              "label": "Male",
              "ndocs": "89076",
              "token": "label_2==Yes"
           },
                          {
              "label": "Female",
              "ndocs": "43567",
              "token": "label_2==no"
           }
        ]
     }
```

In my XML under binning-set I have two bin values. In this case output comes under square brackets, which is as expected.

I want to add same square bracket when I have a single bin value.

```
  <binning-set label="XYZ" bs-id="label_1">
    <bin label="yes" ndocs="9868" token="label_1==yes"/>
  </binning-set>
```

I want response like this

```
    {
        "label": "XYZ",
        "bs-id": "label_1",
        "bin":           **[**  {
           "label": "yes",
           "ndocs": "9868",
           "token": "label_1==yes"
        }
         **]**
     }
```

Can someone please tell me how can I do it using XSLT

Comment: Your XSLT is not going to output JSON at all, right? It’s going to output a <bin type="array"> element. Maybe you’re doing some post-processing of that <bin type="array"> output to generate actual JSON from it? If so, you probably want to include that info in your question.

Comment: What is seems like you’re saying is that in your JSON output, for `bin` you want the value to be an array with one object in it that has `label`, `ndocs`, and `token` members. Maybe you should refine your question to state it that way.